# "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified " error logged by CRON process

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron, tput

We have a shell script which is run by CRON. The shell script in turn runs a python script which downloads files from an FTP server and then runs a java log processor on those files. The process runs just fine, except that I keep on getting CRON emails even if there is no error. At least, I think there is no error. The cron email has two lines, out of which one of the lines is

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

After researching a bit, I found that it's something to do with setting the $TERM variable. I am not sure, how to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something in the script is calling the `tput` binary. `tput` attempts to inspect the `$TERM` variable to determine the current terminal so it can produce the correct control sequences. There isn't a terminal when cron is running so you get that error from `tput`.

You can either manually assign a `TERM` value to the cron job (likely `dumb` or something similar to that) or (and this is likely the better solution) you can find out what is calling `tput` and remove that call.

Comment: I call other libraries, which might be calling tput. I'll try to assign a TERM value and see whether that fixes it

Comment: Thank you! I just set the TERM variable to "dumb" as you suggested, and this worked!

Comment: @Seagull Whatever is calling `tput` is assuming that a terminal is available for output. Cron jobs run without a terminal.  If setting `TERM=dumb` works, that's great, but you *might* want to consider investigating why `tput` is being called. I can imagine that incorrect assumption causing other problems.

Answer (score 17):

The cron daemon is run by 'root' user in its own shell. By default, cron will append a system mail sent to the user running the script (that's why you see the sender as 'root' in the system mail). The 'user' is the user you were logged in as when setting the crontab. The mail will contain console and error messages. On Ubuntu, the mail file is viewable at `/var/mail/<username>`.

If no `$TERM` variable is set, cron will emit a `tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified` error in the mail file. To stop these errors, set the `$TERM` variable using `TERM=dumb` (or another available terminal in your system, like `xterm`) in the crontab. The `toe` command will show you the terminfo definitions on the current system. If you lack that command, you can see the raw data in `/usr/share/terminfo` on most Linux systems.

Even though you have stopped the errors, you may still get appended system mail with console messages. This file will fill up like a log over time, so you may want to stop these messages. To stop cron system mail, set the `MAILTO` variable using `MAILTO=""`

So your crontab might look like:

```
MAILTO=""
TERM=xterm

* * * * * sh /path/to/myscript.sh
```

You can view the crontab (for the user you are signed in as) with 'crontab -l'.

Answer (score 1):

---

### --> MY WORKING SOLUTION FOR THE TPUT-PROBLEM:

---

```
# when $TERM is empty (non-interactive shell), then expand tput with '-T xterm-256color'
[[ ${TERM}=="" ]] && TPUTTERM='-T xterm-256color' \
                  || TPUTTERM=''

declare -r    RES='tput${TPUTTERM} sgr0'       REV='tput${TPUTTERM} rev'
declare -r    fRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 1'    bRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 1'
declare -r    fGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 2'    bGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 2'
...
echo ${fRD}" RED Message: ${REV} This message is RED REVERSE. "${RES}
echo ${fGN}" GREEN Message: ${REV} This message is GREEN REVERSE. "${RES}
...
```

---

this way it makes no sense if there's an interactive or a non-interactive shell - tput still works fine.

*6a5h4*